# Debugging RMI connection

Tags: java, networking, rmi

I know slightly similar questions have been answered to this, but I have read those and I am still having troubles.

I have a server and a client using RMI to connect to each other. The client is at University, and the server is at home. It was done this way around because I have full control of any firewall at home, but not at University, and I felt this would give me the best chance of it working.

I tested them using "localhost" whilst on the same machine and that was fine (both home and uni). I then moved the server onto a VM on my home machine which is running Windows Server 2012. I can remote desktop to that VM as it is set up as a bridged connection and port forwarding is set up. I also forwarded port 1099. The server has right at the top of the main this:

```
System.setProperty("java.rmi.server.hostname", "localhost");
setRegistry(LocateRegistry.createRegistry(1099));
System.setSecurityManager(new RMISecurityManager());
Naming.rebind("rmi://localhost/" + AUTH_OBJECT_BINDING, server);
```

The security manager uses a security.policy file which has in it, for now:

```
grant {
        permission java.security.AllPermission;
};
```

When I try to connect my client to the server, having replaced "localhost" in the naming lookup on the client with my home IP, and having allowed java through the firewall and set up port forwarding, I get this:

```
java.rmi.ConnectException: Connection refused to host: xxx.xxx.xxx.xxx; nested exception is: 
    java.net.ConnectException: Connection timed out: connect
```

Where xxx.xxx.xxx.xxx is my correct home IP address.

So, to test where the problem was, I ran the client on the servers VM, but instead of using localhost I used my external IP. This connected and worked. Therefore, as I can connect using my external IP (starting 217.137...) I think the server is accepting connections fine.

I think this means there is a problem with outbound connections from the University. Is that the only problem this could be? I want to rule everything out. Unfortunately I don't have access to another network which isn't home or uni, but testing using my external IP from home should be the same.

If that is the case, I can set up an SSH server on my home machine which I know works from within the university, and perhaps use putty and tunneling, any guidance on that, or if it's even possible would really help.

Just to be clear, my question is in two parts:
1) Is it likely to be an outbound rule at the university stopping me connecting to my server.
2) If it is, how I can I set up tunelling to work with RMI?

Any help is really appreciated.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

```
System.setProperty("java.rmi.server.hostname", "localhost");
```

This will never work. It needs to be set to the public IP or hostname of your server, via which you can reach it over the Internet.

What you've done here is force every stub to contains 'localhost' as its target address, which will work if the clients are in the same localhost as the servers, but not otherwise. It needs to be something that the client can use to connect to the server.

You also need to export your remote objects on port 1099, via super(1099) in the usual case, and that in turn means you have to run the Registry via LocateRegistry.createRegistry(), making sure to store the result in a static variable so it won't be garbage-collected.

Comment: Hi, thanks for this. So I have set that to 217.137.xxx.xxx (my IP). 
   System.setProperty("java.rmi.server.hostname", "217.137.xxx.xxx");
This makes sense. 
On my Naming.rebind, I use this still (as it needs to be localhost):
Naming.rebind("rmi://localhost/" + AUTH_OBJECT_BINDING, server);

Now when I try connecting from my client (based on the same VM for now) using either localhost or my external IP, I get the connection refused exception.

Comment: Is 217.137.xxx.xxx your public IP address? And are you exporting your remote objects on port 1099? And are you getting the exception on lookup()? or when executing a remote method?

Comment: 217.137.xxx.xxx is my public address. I know it's correct because I am currently using it for remote desktop and it's working fine (I'm at uni at the moment). I don't get the exception when I use loopup, but instead I get it when I call the first method on what is returned. E.g, my client has: 
authObject = (InterfaceAuth) Naming.lookup("rmi://217.137.xxx.xxx/" + AUTH_OBJECT_BINDING)

Then

session = authObject.Authenticate("user", "pass");

I then get from this line the exception, java.rmi.ConnectException: Connection refused to host: 217.137.xxx.xxx;

Comment: I have used this already: setRegistry(LocateRegistry.createRegistry(1099));

I assume that means it will use port 1099

Comment: Good. The fact that the lookup succeeds indicates that the network is basically working, and incidentally refutes @rthur's baseless assertion about RMI and NAT. Now you need to attend the exporting remarks above.

Comment: Ah, I see. Thanks EJP. I tried running the client with the server turned off, and you are correct that an exception was thrown from the lookup() line instead. Therefore it is at least connecting. I'm not sure exactly what I'm doing wrong with how objects are exported, evidently there is a gap in my understanding. After I have called setRegistry(LocateRegistry.createRegistry(1099)), does that not mean that objects will be exported on this port when I then use: Naming.rebind("rmi://localhost/" + AUTH_OBJECT_BINDING, server);

I then get the first object (the auth object).

Comment: And from there I am then using that to authenticate, which returns some session object, and from there the client can do a series of things. Do I need to make changes to every remote object to add in super(1099)?

Comment: It means that the Registry was exported on port 1099. Yes to your final question. Exporting happens on construction, not on bind/rebind.

Comment: EJP, so after adding that to my auth object (which extends UnicastRemoteObject) I get a little bit further, until the next method call which gives me the same exception. I have several UnicastRemoteObjects on my server, so my plan is to go through them and make sure they are calling super(1099). Quick question, if there are many objects using 1099, some belonging to different clients logged in concurrently, does this pose any kind of problem?

Comment: Oh, and also this is working on the same VM, but unfortunately when I run the client from university, the exception is thrown from the lookup(). I guess this means it's a uni firewall issue?

Comment: Thanks for all of the help EJP! I really appreciate it.

Comment: You can have as many remote objects as you like on the same port in a single JVM as long as they don't use a server socket factory, or all use the same server socket factory as determined by its equals() method.

Answer (score 0):

I don't have any specific documentation on hand, but as far as I'm aware RMI does not work well with NAT.

I'm assuming you're still able to connect to the server from inside your network as your router uses nat loopback.

Comment: Thanks for the comment. The VM which is on my home machine uses a direct (bridged) connection, so I think that it should be ok? Or perhaps I am missing something here.

Comment: @EJP As far as I'm aware, running an RMI server behind NAT will only work if the `java.rmi.server.hostname` property is set to a domain name (not an IP) that resolves to the private internal IP inside the NAT network, and the public facing IP outside of the network.

Comment: You are mistaken. It will work if it's set to the public hostname or IP address and the appropriate ports are mapped.

Comment: Fair enough - I've never managed to get it to work successfully behind NAT without using a proper hostname.

Answer (score 0):

I got the same problem which the lookup works but remote invocation failed. My env is little bit different. My RMI application is running on k8s and my code doesn't have any problem on window. But when I deployed the application to k8s, the remote invocation failed. It was painful to find the root cause. Finally I found this page and ThePerson mentioned to add super(1099) to all of the classes which derived from UnicastRemoteObject. That totally solved my problem. Hope it helps others who want to deploy RMI application on k8s.